# Four Analytical Knowledges

Tags: theravada, arahant

Is it still possible to attain the four analytical knowledge? Bare insight seems to be the lowest attainment among arahants.

Comment: I research it and found it here: https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Dhammatthavinicchaya/30-Analytical-Knowledges.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I need some help for correct below writing's grammar.**

I don't understand the question, can you rewrite the question by the below pāli word? Why you think "direct knowledge of the four analytical knowledge"? Because if it means "Abhiññā of Paṭisambhidā", it looks weird according to below title sequence.

### The sequence concept of Theravāda Buddhism

**The sequence concept of Theravāda Buddhism**, start from sīla to **paṭisambhidā**, summarized from paṭisambhidāmagga, visuddhimagga, abhidhamma, atthhakathā, and all sāriputta's canons:

**Paññā** = understand the fact: causes&effects.

**Paṭivedha** = Paññā.

**Ñāṇa** = Expert Paññā.

**Dassana** = View, Understood, **Diṭṭhi**, Cakkhu.

**SammāDiṭṭhi** =SammāDassaṇa.

**Ñātapariññā** = Base of sammādassaṇa.

**Tīraṇapariññā** = Beginning sammādassaṇa practice.

**Pahānapariññā** = Advance sammādassaṇa practice.

**Visuddhi** = The base level which cleared from the extended enemy of the next level's enemy, so it is able to go to the next level.

**Sīla** = Arising physical & verbal behavior.

**SīlaAdhiSikkhā** = Physical & verbal behavior's training that supporting CittaVisuddhi.

**SīlaVisuddhi** = The CittaVisuddhi's base level which cleared from AvītikkamaKilesa, extending from CittaVisuddhi's enemy (PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa), so it is able to go to the next level, CittaVisuddhi.

**AvītikkamaKilesa** = Present life's arising physical & verbal unwholesome, extending from PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa.

**PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa** = Present life's arising mental unwholesome, extending from AnusayaKilesa.

**AnusayaKilesa** = Unwholesome behavior which ready to arise in the name "PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa". It arises as the name "PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa", but it stands as the name "AnusayaKilesa". It is similar to behavior because you can't find your behavior in any organ when you are not doing it, but you know your behavior still available to arise. The arising unwhole behavior is AvītikkamaKilesa/PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa.

**Citta** = Arising mind's behavior, Arising consciousness's behavior, arising Thought's behavior.

**CittaAdhiSikkhā** = Thought behavior's training that supporting DiṭṭhiVisuddhi.

**CittaVisuddhi** = The DiṭṭhiVisuddhi's base level which cleared from PariyuṭṭhānaKilesa, extending from DiṭṭhiVisuddhi's enemy (AttaAnuDiṭṭhiAnusayaKilesa), so it is able to go to the next level, DiṭṭhiVisuddhi.

**SammāDassana** = Right understood of conditioner and conditioned (four noble truth, dependent origination);  diṭṭhivisuddhi + kaṇkhāvitaraṇavisuddhi; nāmarūpapariccheda**ñāṇa**+paccayapariggaha**ñāṇa**; Ñātapariññā; Vipassanā **Paññā**; YathābūtaÑāṇaDassana.

**four noble truth, dependent origination** = conditioner aggregates and conditioned aggregates.

**DiṭṭhiVisuddhi** = The DiṭṭhiVisuddhi's base level which cleared from AttaAnuDiṭṭhi**AnusayaKilesa**, extending from KaṇkhāvitaraṇaVisuddhi's enemy (VisamahetukaDiṭṭhiAnusayaKilesa), so it is able to go to the next level, KaṇkhāvitaraṇaVisuddhi.

**Attā** (of the wrong view) = The misunderstood concept of conditioner aggregates and conditioned aggregates. This misunderstood concept make ordinary people think "there are some controllable aggregates left to be nihilistic or eternal". But the truth is "there are no any controllable aggregates to be nihilistic or eternal. There are only uncontrollable conditioner aggregates and uncontrollable conditioned aggregates".

**AttaAnuDiṭṭhi** = The misunderstood behavior about aggregates whether "some/whole aggregates are Attā".

**KaṅkhāvitaraṇaVisuddhi** = The MaggāmaggaÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi's base level which cleared from VisamahetukaDiṭṭhiAnusayaKilesa, extending from MaggāmaggaÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi's enemy (VipassanāUpakKilesa), so it is able to go to the next level, MaggāmaggaÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi.

**Vipassanā** = SammāDassaṇa; Vipassanā**Paññā**; Vipassanā; Ñātapariññā; **Pajānāti**.

**Anupassnā** = **Ñāṇa**Dassaṇa; Vipassanā**Ñāṇa**; Vipassanā Bhāvanā; Vipassanā Meditation; Tīraṇapariññā + Pahānapariññā; **Anupassati**.

**MaggāmaggaÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi** = SammāDassaṇa at cleared **ñāṇa** level from the extending enemy (the ignorant about the right or wrong practice [maggāmagga;paṭipadā]) of the next level's enemy (the ignorant about the four noble truth), so it is able to go to the next level, to practice watching three characteristics without confusing of the right or wrong practice; BapavaUdayabbaya**ñāṇa**.

**PaṭipadāÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi** = above ÑāṇaDassana at cleared **ñāṇa** level  from the extending enemy (the ignorant about the four noble truth) of the next level enemy (the ignorant about the four noble truth), so it is able to go to the next level, to stop the ignorant about the four noble truth **forever** by the **complete&perfect** watching three characteristics; From Bhaṅga**ñāṇa** to Anulomañāṇa.

**ÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi** = above ÑāṇaDassana at cleared **ñāṇa** level(enlightenment) from the extending enemy (fetters; saṇyojana) of the next level enemy (rebirth; becoming; bhava; paṭisandhiviññāṇa), so it is able to go to the next level, to stop the rebirth as many as the level of the enlightenment.

**Paṭisambhidā** = ÑāṇaDassanaVisuddhi according to Abhi. Vibhaṅgo [ñāṇavatthuvibhaṅga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=35&A=8855&h=%C4%81panna,Bh%C4%81van%C4%81may%C4%81%20pa%C3%B1%C3%B1%C4%81#hl), Sutta. Khu. Paṭisambhidāmaggo mahāvaggo ñāṇakathā [mātikā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=31&A=2&h=sutamaye%20%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a%E1%B9%83,dubhatovu%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81naviva%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADanepa%C3%B1%C3%B1%C4%81%20magge%20%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a%E1%B9%83,pa%E1%B9%ADisambhide%20%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a%E1%B9%83,iddhividhe%20%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a%E1%B9%83#hl), Paṭisambhidāmaggo's [atthakathā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=47&A=1&h=Bahumpi:n%C4%81manatthi:n%C4%81ma%20natthi#hl), Visuddhimagga [Khandhaniddeso](https://thaipitaka.gitlab.io/palipack/visuddhimagga-2of2.html?pg=117). All ariya must enlighten Paṭisambhidā of own meditation. They can analysis everything about own meditation (super mundane jhāna), but **they maybe don't know about mundane jhāna, Abhiññā, and the other practitioners' meditation.** They enlightened Paṭisambhidā of own meditation only, they may be not the Paṭisambhidappatto.

**Tevijjo** = Ariya who is an expert, vasī, of jhāna. That expertise increases the power of ÑāṇaDassana to be greater, to be able to recall many past lives and to be able to recall many deaths&rebirths more than the practitioner who is no an expert of jhāna. Normally, the only vipassanā practitioner can recall about 1-2 past lives, but the expert of jhāna can recall more than that. The expert of jhāna spend the lesser time to recall the past lives at the same number of life.

**Abhiññā** = Special practice of an expert, vasī, of **jhāna**. Two Abhiññā, Pubbenivāsānussatiñāṇa and Cutūpapatañāṇa, have the similar practice as ÑāṇaDassaṇa, so the expert of jhāna can enlighten as a Tevijjo easier.

**Chaḷabhiñño** = Ariya who is an expert, vasī, of **every Abhiññā**.

**Paṭisambhidappatto** = Chaḷabhiñño who is an expert of **own and the others' Paṭisambhidā**.

**For the example question:**

> if I become a stream-enterer I will automatically have four analytical knowledge right? Will I also have three clear knowledge and six higher knowledge?

if you become a stream-enterer without being an expert of jhāna&abhiñña&paṭisambhidā, you are a stream-enterer who automatically have only four analytical knowledge right of your meditation. You are only a Sukkhavipassako, but you are not Paṭisambhidappatto, Chaḷabhiñño, Tevijjo.

**For the conclusion:**

[image: The sequence concept of Theravāda Buddhism]

### Buddhism's Existing Period Counting

The contexts about Buddhism's Existing Period Counting appear as **3 tenses** in Aṭṭakathā:

**1. The existing enlightenment of the current Buddha's follower (45BBE - about 5,000 BE):**

Buddhism's existing period counting of current Buddha  according to Vinaya.A. (samanta.3) [Bhikkhunikkhandhakavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=3&A=9179&h=vassasahass#hl), An.A. (manoratha.1) [Dutiyapamadadivaggavannana](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=1833&h=Soparihayamano%20patisambhidato,vassasahassameva,Eteneva%20upayena%20anagaminosakadagamino%20sotapannati&modeTY=2&pagebreak=#hl):

1st 1000 years after **Gotama**, Current Buddha, died:

> Arahanta with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur=>

2nd 1000 years after **GotamaSambuddha** died:

> Arahanta with Six Higher Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Arahanta with Three Clear Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Arahanta via Insight-only still occur=>>

3rd 1000 years after **GotamaSambuddha** died:

> Anāgāmi with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Anāgāmi with Six Higher Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Anāgāmi with Three Clear Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Anāgāmi via Insight-only still occur=>>

4th 1000 years after **GotamaSambuddha** died:

> Sakadāgāmi with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sakadāgāmi with Six Higher Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sakadāgāmi with Three Clear Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sakadāgāmi via Insight-only still occur=>>

Final 1000 years after **GotamaSambuddha** died:

> Sotāpanna with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sotāpanna with Six Higher Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sotāpanna with Three Clear Knowledges still occur=>
>
> Sotāpanna via Insight-only still occurs until the end of final 1000 years.

**2. The previous KassapaBuddha (uncountable millions of years ago):**

**Kassapa**SamBuddha's, previous Buddha's, Buddhism existing period counting appear in Di.A. (sumangala.3) [Sampasadaniyasuttavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=6&A=1460&w=&modeTY=2&pagebreak=1&h=kassapabuddhakalato,atthasi.#hl); It using the past tense verbs). And Saṃ.A. (sārattha.2) [Saddhammappaṭirūpakasuttavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=12&A=4997&h=kassapasamm%C4%81sambuddhak%C4%81le%20kapilo#hl), which connects to that Sampasadaniyasuttavaṇṇanā:

1st 1000 years after **Kassapa**, previous Buddha, died:

> Arahanta with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur=>

2rd 1000 years after **Kassapa**, previous Buddha, died:

> Arahanta with Six Higher Knowledges still occur=>

3th 1000 years after **Kassapa**, previous Buddha, died:

> Arahanta with Three Clear Knowledges still occur=>

4th 1000 years after **Kassapa**, previous Buddha, died:

> Arahanta via Insight-only still occur=>>

Final 1000 years  after **Kassapa**, previous Buddha, died:

> Pāṭimokkha memorizer still occurs until the end of final 1000 years.

**3. The current Buddha's living time (45 - 0 BBE):**

The sequence of existing enlightenment of the Buddha's followers just in current alive buddha's time, not died, appear in Saṃ.A. (sārattha.2)  [Saddhammappaṭirūpakasuttavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=12&A=4997&h=Pa%E1%B9%ADhamabodhiya%E1%B9%83#hl).**It's explaining the Buddha's answer to KassapaThera's question** in Sutta. Saṃ. Ni. [Saddhammappaṭirūpakasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=16&A=5317&eng=metta_e&eng=accesstoinsight_than):

> "What is the cause, lord, what is the reason, why before there were fewer training rules and yet more monks established in final gnosis, whereas now there are more training rules and yet fewer monks established in final gnosis?"

**At alive GotamaSamBuddha's time after he has enlightened,** at the beginning Arahanta with Four Analytical Knowledges still occur. As time went by Arahanta with Six Higher Knowledges still occur Arahanta with Three Clear Knowledges still occur. As time went by Arahanta via Insight-only still occur. As time went by Anāgāmī still occur. As time went by Sakadāgāmi still occur. As time went by Sotāpanna still occur. As time went by Sīpavanta still occur.

---

A short term of all above Buddha's periods are up and down depending on the situation, but it tends to go down in long-term of every period. It's something like this:

[image]
Cr. wikipedia

Comment: So can we attain anagami with four analytical knowledge?

Comment: We must attain ariya-magga with four analytical knowledge, but it doesn't means we will be paṭisambhidappatto after enlightened. Paṭisambhidappatto requires more qualification than normal Paṭisambhidā, such as being the expert of jāna, Abhiñña, and  Paṭisambhidā.

Comment: Are there any method to attain Ariya-magga with four analytical knowledge?

Comment: [Paṭisambhidāmagga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=31&A=2) means the method to attain Ariya-magga with four analytical knowledge. You can use [path of purification](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf) instead. Again, every Ariya has four analytical knowledge, but only the Qualify ariya can be paṭisambhidappatto. I recommend Pa-Auk, if you want to enlighten with  four analytical knowledge. https://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/

Comment: so I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Can we stay attain arahantship with four analytical knowledge or can we attain anagami with four analytical knowledge but will we lose the four analytical knowledge after becoming arahant?

Comment: I am sorry, I have forgotten the point. According to aṭṭhakathā, nowadays we can attain anāgāmi with four analytical knowledge at most. Ariya never loses the four analytical knowledge. Every ariya has four analytical knowledge.

Comment: So all ariya automatically get four analytical knowledge after their attainment?

Comment: All ariya practiced four analytical knowledge, so they all get the four analytical knowledge automatically after their attainment. They graduated what they have practiced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87240/discussion-between-thedbsguy-and-bonn).

Answer (score 0):

I've read a book (in Chinese) by Ven. Mahinda (a Buddhist monk from Pa-Auk Myanmar Forest Tradition) and here is a rough translation (by me) with regards to the 5000 years of Dhamma.

His source is from commentary on Digha Nikaya (D.A.3.161)

```
1st 1000 years    Arahant with Four Analytical Knowledges
2nd 1000 years    Arahant with Six Higher Knowledges
3rd 1000 years    Arahant with Three Clear Knowledges
4th 1000 years    Arahant via Insight-only
Final 1000 years  1st Three Paths and Fruits (i.e. impossible to attain Arahant-hood)
```

The table above shows the highest attainment possible for each of the 1000 years. If we were to solely based on this commentary, the **Four Analytical Knowledges** and **Six Higher Knowledges** cannot be attained any more.

Comment: So does that mean that arahant via jhana are not possible anymore? So we can only become arahant by practicing vipassana. Can we still have the six higher knowledge is the three clear knowledge?

Comment: Hi, the historical Buddha passed away for about 25xx years ago. Thus, we are at the "3rd 1000 years" now. Therefore Six Higher Knowledges is also impossible. Three Clear Knowledges is the highest anyone can achieve now.

Comment: Hi, for your other question regarding jhana and vipassana, I'm not very sure. But you can take a look at the note number 2 in this Sutta (https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.163.than.html)

Comment: Buddhaghosa said that in our current time only arahant via bare insight is possible? I don’t know which is true.

Comment: @BurningJade Please read my answer in the title "Buddhism's Exist Period Counting". Give the whole answer to Pa-auk teacher and tell him "the answer from one who knows kalāpa is SamūhaUpādāPaññatti". Tell him that this answer can stop all confusing of "Buddhism's Exist Period Counting".