# In the trisvabhava theory, is the consummate nature inflected by past present and future conditions?

Tags: causes

In the [trisvabhava](https://www.britannica.com/topic/trisvabhava) theory, is the consummate nature inflected by past present and future conditions? Or is it always the same and independent of causal conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes consummate nature is inflected by past present and future conditions but it is not inflected by time. Do any other mahayana object?
If something is composed of multiple parts and one of those parts is timeless and not inflected by time. Then the whole cannot be inflected by time even if it is composed of another part that is inflected by karma (including past present and future conditions).
My advice: become enlightened and try to prove whether or not you are existing in reality as we know it, or not.

Comment: It's good (though not required) if an answer is "based on" something -- perhaps a "reference" (to scripture), and/or personal "experience". A simple yes/no answer isn't very informative -- e.g. it doesn't tell the OP how to "know for themselves" whether something is true.

Answer (score 0):

All conditions are impermanent. Consummate nature arises due to conditions created by conditioners. Because conditions change in future therefore consummate nature is inflected by a sense of future time when new conditions will arise and old conditions will decay.
Therefore not getting involved with sanskharas of consummateness , one should seek cessation of craving by breaking the chain of dependent origination.